# Как сохранить photo внутри static/app/images из views.py если views.py не видит путь в Django

Tags: python, django

```
FileNotFoundError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\rasul\\OneDrive\\Документы\\GitHub\\django_projects\\coolsia\\static\\hill\\images\\test.png'
```

Не видит путь как можно этого сделать. index(request): из views.py  может сохранять только внутри приложении

```
def index(request):

    qr_image = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST['data']
        img = qrcode.make(data)
        img.save(os.path.join(django_settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'hill', 'images', 'test.png'))
        qr_image = True

    context3 = {
            'cats': cats,
            'menu': menu,
            'title': 'Басқы бет',
            'cat_selected': 0,
            'qr_image': qr_image,
        }

    return render(request, 'hill/index.html', context=context3)
```

внутри index.html все работает

```
{% extends 'hill/base.html' %}


{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<br>
<br>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Введите адрес сайта</h3>
    <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="Получить QR код">
</form>

{% if qr_image %}
    <h4>Ваш QR код:</h4>
    <img src="{% static 'hill/images/test.png'%}">
{% endif %}

{%endblock%}
```

Эта сохраняющий модель дает ошибка

```
img.save(os.path.join(django_settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'hill', 'images', 'test.png'))
```

Comment: а зачем? папка `static`  (STATIC_ROOT) нужна для "постоянных" файлов, которые были поставлены вместе с сайтом. для файлов закружаемых, генерируемых, еще каких либо - существует папка `media` (MEDIA_ROOT) (ну не папка media, а то что укажие в MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: а вообще проверьте, что папка существует. никто за вас ее не создаст в вашем случае

Comment: и как сохранить любой другой файл из views.py внутри media и как открыть media файл в html